# Issue in setting an image as the background a of a scene in Manim Community v0.17.0

Tags: python, manim

Issue in setting an image as the background a of a scene in Manim Community v0.17.0

```
from manim import *

class ImageFromArray(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.background_image =r"C:\Users\Shobhan\Desktop\program\bb.jpg"
```

is not working...what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Manim page](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.types.image_mobject.ImageMobject.html)

```
class ImageFromArray(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        image = ImageMobject(np.uint8([[0, 100, 30, 200],
                                       [255, 0, 5, 33]]))
        image.height = 7
        self.add(image)
```

Try creating an `ImageMobject` and then use the method `add()`.

Where the class `ImageMobject` seems to accept a path in its constructor:

```
class ImageMobject(filename_or_array, scale_to_resolution=1080, invert=False, image_mode='RGBA', **kwargs
```